# Laravel 404 on production server NGINX

Tags: nginx, laravel-5

I have Laravel with `NGINX` on my production server, I have added new routes and they work fine on the `localhost`. But in production, it returns `404` by Laravel.

```
1. I have restart NGINX but still no result. 
2. I look a the route list and they are present.
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;



        root /var/www/laravel/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name www.somesite.jp;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }


        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: can u add you nginx configration file

Comment: @JigneshJoisar sure. pls check.

Comment: your nginx configuration is correct my opinion

Comment: Nginx has very helpful `error.log`. Did you look in there?

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov Nothing there about this routes :((

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov is this the right log file `/var/log/nginx# sudo nano access.log` ?

Comment: Not `access.log`, but `error.log.`

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov nothing there as well ... :(

Comment: Two options: (1) [the log level](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) is too high; (2) `404` is returned from your backend (Laravel).

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov Sorry,  yes the 404 is returned by Laravel. But it is working on localhost ...

Comment: I cannot help you with Laravel. But since we've learned your problem is with Laravel, I guess it makes sense for you to provide more information on your Laravel setup in the question to ease life of a Laravel expert 

Answer (score 1):

With me, I have found that localhost often doesn't mind the case on routes, but in production, getting the case correct is important. Same true on Controller file names etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  so it is my bad. Problem was that on the server there were different conditions and I was trying to get `User::findOrFail($userId)` where ID didn't exist and it returns  Laravel 404 error!